# What is a seed in relation to a random number generation algorithm and why is computer time used to create this seed more often than not?

Tags: random, language-agnostic

I read that *seeds* are used to initialize random number generators. But seems like the randomness of the seed doesn't matter much for getting good randomness from the generator. So I want to understand what is a *seed* actually? Why is it called so? And lastly why *time* in a computer system is used to generate such seeds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pseudo-random number generator produces a sequence of numbers. It isn't truly random, but generally a mathematical calculation which produces an output that matches some desirable distribution, and without obvious patterns. In order to produce such a sequence, there must be *state* stored for the generator to be able to generate the next number in that sequence. The state is updated each time using some part of the output from the previous step.

Seeding explicitly initialises this state. A 'seed' is a starting point, from which something grows. In this case, a sequence of numbers.

This can be used either to always generate the same sequence (by using a known constant seed), which is useful for having deterministic behaviour. This is good for debugging, for some network applications, cryptography, etc.

Or, in situations where you want the behaviour to be unpredictable (always different each time you run a program, a card game perhaps), you can seed with a number likely to be continually changing, such as time.

The 'randomness' of the sequence does not depend on the seed chosen, though it does depend on not *reseeding* the sequence.

Comment: Can you give a small example explaining this?
For example, lets say we want to generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 10. Now we set seed as 1. So the first random number would be generated with 1 as starting point and applying some logic to convert into another number. Now this number would be seed for the next random number. Is that what we are referring to?